# How to set order by id desc in AsEnumerable in web api c#

Tags: c#, webapi

Here is my code:

```
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<SPS_TRAN> Get()
        {
            //returning all records of table tblMember.  
            return db.SPS_TRANs.ToList().AsEnumerable();
        }
```

How to get the data in descending order.. `Order by id desc`
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show the source for class `SPS_TRAN`, hence I can only give you an idea on how to do this.

**Short answer**

```
// GET api/<controller>
public IEnumerable<SPS_TRAN> Get()
{
    //returning all records of table tblMember.  
    return db.SPS_TRANs
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
        .ToArray();
}
```

**Longer answer with mock data**

I'll use this definition for class `SPS_TRAN`

```
public class SPS_TRAN
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then a controller method with mock data

```
public IEnumerable<SPS_TRAN> Get()
{
    SPS_TRAN[] arrayOfSpsTrans = {
        new SPS_TRAN
        {
            Id = 1, 
            Name = "~name1~"
        },
        new SPS_TRAN
        {
            Id = 2, 
            Name = "~name2~"
        }
    };

    return arrayOfSpsTrans
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
        .ToArray();
}
```